I planted seeds from 3 different kind of papaya
I buy different papayas'.  I threw seeds out in different places and was surprised they grew, so transplanted to pots.  Now that they are big 2-3 feet tall i plan on putting them in the ground this fall (one is already in grown and about 6 feet tall.  Is there a problem with the different kinds of papayas" being planted about 7 feet away from each other.

No, it should be an issue if you place 7 feet away from each other as it's the fall season it will give them enough time to establish their roots before winter.
Just make sure a few things while doing this, soil management, pollination, monitoring their space and growth, a good amount of sunlight and water as papaya plants need full sun and well-draining soil, keep an eye on pests or disease.
